# Create Google Calendar event with a public hangout

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I need to create a calendar event with a public Hangouts link attached to it.

I'm currently using the Node.js google client library to create an event on a Google Calendar using a service account in my organisation. The event is being created successfully, and has a Hangouts link attached to it, but the Hangout is only accessible to members of our organisation, everyone else needs to request access to the Hangouts before they can join it.

The problem is, we're creating these events on behalf of our clients (who are not part of our organisation) and we don't want to have to continuously go into the Hangout before our clients join just to let them in. That won't scale well.

How would I go about creating an event on our google calendar that anyone can join without requesting access?

Comment: You can try to follow the instruction presented in [this Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6138421?hl=en). By following the instruction, you will allow external guests to join using the meeting link by default.

Comment: That seems to allow all hangouts across the organisation to be public. I just need the hangouts for a particular calendar to be public, using the API request.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @Walter

Comment: @AdrianCarolli I wasn't able to get this to work no, I left a few months later so not sure if it ever got working.